# purrr equivalent of lapply to return multi-element list?

Tags: r, purrr

I have a population of individuals that have attributes for whether or not they are alive, their sex, and age:

```
ind <- vector(mode="list", 10)
  for(i in seq(ind)){
    ind[[i]]$alive <- 1 
    ind[[i]]$sex <- sample(c("female","male"),1) 
    ind[[i]]$age <- round(runif(1, min=1, max=10))
  }
ind
```

Using lapply, I can increase the age of each individual, and get the list of individuals back with all of their attributes:

```
lapply(ind,function(x){x$age <- x$age+1; x})
```

Is there a map function from purrr that can do the same exact thing (give the same output as lapply)? When I use map(), I only get back a list of ages, and not all of the attributes for each individual:

```
map(ind, ~.$age+1)
```

Comment: It's probably not the cleanest way, but the same logic as you used in `lapply` works for `map` too - `map(ind, ~{.$age <- .$age+1; .})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the help files, it looks like `?update_list` is what you want:

```
map(ind, update_list, age = ~age + 1)
```

So apply to each item of `ind` the `update_list` function, and replace the `age` variable with the result of the expression `age + 1`.

Comment: any thoughts on how to make this conditional? Not in my original question, but I'm wondering how this can be changed to apply ageing just to males for example (this is not realistic, just wondering how to include a conditional here as well...)

Comment: @jason - maybe something with `replace` - `age = ~replace(age, age=="Male", age[age=="Male"] + 1)` (untested code)